# What's the recommended way to handle users who are registered by someone else (i.e. can't choose a password)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have an app where users are not self-registered, i.e. another user adds them to the system, and they are emailed with their login details. What's the best way to handle this in terms of creating the user and handling the password?

It's the sort of thing where a user is invited in to the system by someone else, answers a questionnaire, then doesn't need to log in again until some point in the future where they might be invited again by someone different, so ideally they will need to be reminded of their login details in the email rather than having to reset their password every time. Obviously in an ideal world people would just remember their passwords but the situation it's used in and the infrequency of access means that people simply don't remember, and the process needs to be as hassle-free as possible to ensure user participation.

The old version of the site used Webforms and ASP.Net Membership with encrypted passwords, which could be retrieved and sent to the user each time they are invited. What is the best practise for Identity, where the user does not supply their own password? Are there other options for logging in users such as:

- A unique-link provided in the email which authenticates the user?
- A separately encrypted 'passcode' field stored in the `AspNetUsers`
  table which can be decrypted and sent each email?

It's worth pointing out that users with admin-level access to the site would still have the usual secure Identity user/pass setup, my problem is just with the lower level users.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You have to send the user some kind of login information. What do you want to prevent? Please [edit] your question to elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why don't the users remember their login details between logins?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, sadly that is the situation, it covers all levels of user some of whom are not very computer literate or would be using shared machines. Ideally I'd like to do away with the password entirely and just have a unique link that identifies the user.

Comment: @Progman Updated my question as requested. It's hard to explain but really just looking for advice on what other methods could be used rather than the usual hashed password with Identity.

Comment: Best practice is to never ever store passwords (encrypted or not). Instead, store a salted hash of the password, so that no one, even you, can reverse engineer the actual password. A unique link for each used would be easily cracked, most simply by looking at the browser history. It sounds like you need to do a bit more research into security. A user who forgets their password every day is indistinguishable from someone hacking your system.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am experienced in security, and I have petitioned for hashed passwords for all for a long time, but the combination of low-literacy userbase and need for maximum user participation has prevented me from implementing proper security. I was just hoping there was a workaround that I didn't know about which caters for this situation of users not registering themselves and only logging in potentially once every 6 months or a year. I think I'm going to have to bite the bullet and just go with users setting a password on first login and dealing with the customer backlash :(

Answer (score 2):

I would forget completely about passwords in this case. ASP.NET Identity provides you with one-time codes that you can use for this.

[This tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity) shows you in the section ["Set up email confirmation"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity#set-up-email-confirmation) how to send one-time codes through mail (these are generated by ASP.NET Identity itself):

```
string html = "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + message.Body + "\">link</a><br/>";
```

You can easily modify that as well as the behavior when the user clicks that link to match what you want to do here.

Comment: I have used these before but I'm not sure they would work in this situation due to the limited validity timespan. Might have a play with them though and see if they work as needed

Comment: Acutally as @HereticMonkey commented in the original post, this would be vulnerable by looking at browser history. Maybe if I combine it with a passcode supplied in the email, that way only people who have the original email can gain access.

Comment: @RossJ It's a **one-time** code for a reason, you cannot use it twice. There's also a method that allows you to generate a code for copy-paste rather than having to click a link

Comment: Oh right, I wasn't aware they literally only work once... I thought they were valid for as long as the validity period specified in the `UserManager`?